# twig template loop associate array output with key

Tags: php, templates, loops, symfony, twig

I have two arrays which I know are 25 items in length.  I would like to create a for loop that iterates over them both at the same time so I can output the value.  The below does not work but it will hopefully demonstrate what im trying to achieve

```
{% for i in 0..25 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{sourceList[i]}}</td> 
    <td>{{destinationList[i]}}</td>
  <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why should this not work. With some tweaks and making sure the syntax is fine there is nothing wrong with this logic that will stop it from working

Comment: Its the syntax that im having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work but you could try this instead :

```
{% for i in range(0, 25) %}
<tr>
    <td>{{sourceList[i]}}</td> 
    <td>{{destinationList[i]}}</td>
  <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This will display **26** items

See more here : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html

Are you sure of your arrays content ?